# Is number in JavaScript immutable?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript numbers- immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248568/javascript-numbers-immutable)

I read Douglas Crockford's book JavaScript: the Good Parts. It says the number in JavaScript is immutable. But numbers in JavaScript is copied by value and we can 
use operator ++ to change the value. So why say it's immutable? and further, if it's
immutable, why numbers are copied by value?

Comment: your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248568/javascript-numbers-immutable

Comment: @Gatekeeper I think they are different

Comment: In contrast to other languages, the ++ operator in JavaScript doesn't change the value of a number but creates a new number. Try `    let n = 0;
    let m = n;
    console.log(m, n, m === n);
    ++m;
    console.log(m, n, m === n);
`

Answer (score 6):

They are immutable because they are copied by value.

When you do

```
var x = 4;
x += 1;
```

you haven't changed the number `4` into the number `5`. You have changed the value stored in the variable `x` from `4` to `5`.

Comment: If I changed the value stored in variable x, why say it's immutable. And I think "immutable" means you can't change the memory which variable point to.

Comment: And I think += is also an assignment which you bind the variable to another memory if x is immutable

Answer (score 0):

When you modify the members of an object, you modify its contents. The value of the variable (i.e. the reference) stays the same. This is mutable,

When you declare a string, it has a value, but when you change that value a new string is actually created. This means it is immutable.

Similarly with numbers. You can't change a 3 to be a 4. A 3 is always 3, never anything else. So when you assign a variable to another number, you are creating a new number in memory, not assigning the contents of some memory pointed to by some variable to a different value.

Comment: what about ++ operator, it also create a new number in memory?

Comment: x++ is identical to x+=1, so yes.

Comment: I think it's quite confusing. In python, integer is also immutable and python doesn't provide ++ operator. And I think the reason behind it is that ++ make people think value is changed in-place. And I doesn't understand why JavaScript behave in such an unusual way

Comment: Its not just JavaScript that supports `++`. Its C#, Java, C, C++ to name a few. It's just shorthand for x = x + 1, however the concept of pre and post increment is also supported (`x++` = pre `++x` = post). the short of it is, that its a decades old concept, and JavaScript is not behaving in an unusual way.