# Javascript Compiler behavior - double plus for array of empty array and array of zero is.. ONE

Tags: javascript

My question may be already answered, but I could not find it not in Search Engines google or bing doesn't like '+' (plus) sign in search request.

**Anyway, why this is zero**

```
+[[]][0] // = 0
```

**and this is one**

```
++[[]][0] // = 1
```

**UPD:**
Michael Berkowski have a good answer, but I steal don't understand one thing

if `[[]][0]` evaluates to an empty array, then why `++[]` is `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation`

**UPD2:**
now I get it.. it seems I was trying to type ++0 in console and getting an Error, but I should be using var a = 0; ++a

Comment: They do when you use `""`. Though I doubt you'd have found a ready-made explanation for this exact code -- you have to break it down into its components and research each language feature individually. Where did you see this, and why do you need it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I saw that in some videocast about javascript.. this was some kind of joke, but i really want to understand that..

Comment: @Ai_boy Regarding the addendum to your question, I'm not certain, but that might even vary by browser. In Chrome, I see the same result.  You can apply the prefix/postifx `++` to a variable, but not to a scalar value. You can't do `++(+"")` either, although you can evaluate `+""` to `0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is best explored by breaking down the way its components evaluate.

`[[]][0]` alone evaluates to the empty array `[]`.  By adding `+` in front, you cast its string representation to an integer 0 (like saying `+4` or `-3`) via a unary positive operator.  `+0` is just `0`.

`++` as a numeric operator, also casts the empty string to an integer `0`, but applies its operation (the prefix increment) resulting  `1`.

```
[[]][0]
// [] empty array
[[]][0].toString()
// ""

// Unary + casts the empty string to an integer
+("")
// 0

// Prefix increment on an empty string results in 1 (increments the 0)
var emptyString = "";
++emptyString;
// 1
```

Comment: More precisely, `++` first casts to an integer and then (pre)increments. That's why you don't need `++(+[[]][0])`.

Comment: @TedHopp Yes that is a better explanation.

Comment: could you plz explain "applies the prefix increment to 1." more in detail?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i'm talking about second case "++[[]][0] // = 1"

Comment: @Ai_boy `++0` is `1`. `++` takes the number next to it, increments by one, and returns the result.

Comment: @bfavaretto now I get it.. it seems I was trying to type `++0` in console and getting an Error, but I should be using `var a = 0; ++a`

Comment: The question is... why does `++` work on `[5][0]` but not on `5`? Similarly, on `["5"][0]` but not on `"5"`

Comment: @aditsu What specifically are you trying? Are you doing `++[5][0]` and then trying `++5`?  If so, you simply cannot increment an int primitive like `++5`.  Doing `[5][0]` returns the zero'th index of the array `[5]` then increments it, so rather than incrementing the primitive `5` you are incrementing the value referenced at the `[0]` position of the array `[5]`. Since you are incrementing the array value by its reference, it seems to work. It's like doing `x = [5]; ++x[0]` which increments it to 6.

Comment: @aditsu The number `5` itself [is immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248568/javascript-numbers-immutable) but the array element is mutable.