# How to bind to textfields without state in react/redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am a bit new to react/redux

From what I understand state is to be immutable in redux, but when searching for component binding examples I keep seeing things such as

```
<TextField
  id="usernameId"
  value={this.state.username}    
  onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
/>

public handleUsernameChange = (event: any) => {
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value
        });
}
```

To my understanding this is mutating State. When I change the binding to use a global instead. In the callbacks the values are being changed and updated, however the UI is not observing these variables.

I guess this question is just a sanity check.
Is this acceptable in redux?

Please note I am not using other libraries at the moment

Code I've tried without using state

```
   let loginInfomation: ILoginInformation = new LoginInformation;
...
   <TextField
      id="usernameId"
      value={this.loginInformation.username}    
      onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
    />

    public handleUsernameChange = (event: any) => {
          this.loginInfomation.username = event.target.value
       });
    }
```

Comment: You're replacing with new state value and that's okay.

Comment: You may also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248568/javascript-numbers-immutable) about immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are primitive types, and they are immutable by default.
You want to look out from mutating Objects and Arrays which are reference type.

This is OK:

```
let x = 8;
x = 5; // no mutation here
```

This is considered mutation:

```
let arr = [1,2,3];
arr.push(4); // this is mutating the existing array
```

So with reference types you can create new Objects or arrays:

```
let arr = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [...arr, 4]; // creating new array;
```

Comment: Thank you that explains a lot and I suddenly feel like I understand the projects code a lot better

Comment: @SCFi Glad it helps. I recommend reading the answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value) for ref vs value

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Middleware to add [Immutability Checkcheck](https://medium.com/@spencer_carli/setting-up-your-redux-store-3016eff82d83) to your code:

In your configureStore.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducers from '../reducers';
import immutableCheckMiddleWare from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant';

export function configureStore(initialState) { 
     return createStore(
       rootReducer,
       initialState,
       applyMiddleware(immutableCheckMiddleWare())
    )
}
```