# Javascript functions - copied by reference, but what's going on here?

Tags: javascript, function, reference, variable-assignment

Given functions in JavaScript are a reference type (copied by reference, unlike simple types), what precisely is going on here?

```
var func = function() { alert(1); };
var func_alias = func;
var func = function() { alert(2); };
func_alias(); //1
```

If `func_alias` is a reference to `func`, **why is it non-updating? Wouldn't you expect its invocation (line 4) to return `2`?**

This is different behaviour from other by-reference examples:

```
var obj = {prop: 'val'};
var obj_alias = obj;
obj.prop = 'updated val';
alert(obj_alias.prop); //updated val - not original one
```

`func_alias` seems to have kept a copy of the original, pre-overwrite `func` - in short, it seems to behave as though it's copied it by value. This of course is disproven by:

```
var func = function(){}
var func_alias = func;
func === func_alias; //true
```

Comment: Identical to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326072/javascript-function-pointer-assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var func = function() { alert(1); };`

Here a new function is created and a reference to it is copied to `func`

`var func_alias = func;`

The function reference stored is `func` is assigned to another variable `func_alias`

`var func = function() { alert(2); };`

Another new function is created and a reference to it is assigned to `func`. The reference to the first function stored in `func` is lost. But since you saved it in `func_alias` before overwriting `func`, it can still be called.

`func_alias();`

`func_alias` was assigned a reference to the first function in step 2 (and wasn't overwritten after that point). So the first function is called.

---

**EDIT #1**

As per your second example using an object:

```
var obj = {prop: 'val'};
```

Here, a new object is created and a reference to it is assigned to `obj`

```
var obj_alias = obj;
```

The reference is copied to another variable obj_alias

```
obj.prop = 'updated val';
```

Here you are not overwriting the value of `obj`, but only overwriting a property of the object pointed to by that reference stored in obj. The value of `obj` (i.e. reference to the object created in first step) remains intact.

In your function example, you were actually overwriting the variable `func` with a new function reference.

```
alert(obj_alias.prop);
```

The value of `obj_alias` as well as that of `obj` is still the same, since you haven't overwritten either. They both hold a reference to the object created in step 1.

---

**EDIT #2**

This can maybe be explained well in **C** terms.

- When you create an object via `var obj = {prop: 'val'};` - lets say the object is stored at address 0x0001 in memory. i.e. the actual value of obj is 0x0001
- When you assign it to `obj_alias`, `obj_alias` also gets the value 0x0001 - now both variables point to something stored at address 0x0001
- When you do `obj.x = y`, you aren't overwriting the value of `obj`, but only using `obj` to access the object stored at 0x0001 and modifying one of its properties.

Comment: +1. Interesting. I'm intrigued as to why functions should behave differently from objects (see my second example). Is this difference by design or for any reason?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is

in the first piece of code, you let a variable refer to another object.

in the second piece of code, you changed the property of the object, the two variable is refer to the same object.

```
var func = function() { alert(1); };
var func_alias = func; // func_alias refer to the first function.
var func = function() { alert(2); }; // let func refer to another function, but won't affect func_alias
func_alias(); //1
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean, therefore, that functions are copied by value, not reference? That's what the answers on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326072/javascript-function-pointer-assignment) seem to suggest.

Comment: No. If you assigned a function to `a` then the value of `a` to `b` then assigned something to `a.x` then you can access that same something as `b.x`. You can only ever access a function by reference, and when you copy a variable containing a reference to a function then you copy the reference.

Comment: Thanks, xdazz and Quentin for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider your program code to be a large warehouse that allows you to store and use objects.
Then your code does the following:
Line 1 - let's store the function SOMEWHERE and I (first variable) will remember where it is [you don't (and can't) specify particular location here].
Line 2 - let someone else remember where the function is stored too.
Line 3 - let's store ANOTHER function SOMEWHERE and I (first variable) will remember where it is [you don't (and can't) specify particular location here].
Line 4 - ask the guy from Line 2 where my function is.

What is you expected result?