# Javascript object methods

Tags: javascript

Why I cannot do this?

```
var MyObject = {}
MyObject.foo = function(){
  this.sayhello = function(){
    alert('Hello');
  }
}
MyObject.foo.sayhello();
```

Any ideas on how it could be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Function-Pointer Assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326072/javascript-function-pointer-assignment)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326072/javascript-function-pointer-assignment

Comment: @atk, I don't believe that linked question is related to what's being asked here.

Comment: @zzzBov: You're right, it's not exactly the answer, but it gives part of the answer - that is, code that works (where the question appears to ask because their code doesn't work).

Answer (score 6):

within `foo`, `this` references `MyObject`, which means that after:

```
MyObject.foo();
```

you can call:

```
MyObject.sayhello();
```

If you want to be able to call `MyObject.foo.sayhello()`, you need `sayhello` to be a function on `MyObject.foo`:

```
var MyObject = {}
MyObject.foo = function () {...};
MyObject.foo.sayhello = function () {
    alert('hello');
}
```

If you don't need `foo` to also be a function, you could simply declare:

```
var MyObject = {
    foo: {
        sayhello: function () {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    }
}
```

which would allow you to call:

```
MyObject.foo.sayhello();
```

Comment: this is ok, but it's not mapped by netbeans navigator..., I have to use commas between functions

Comment: I should also mention that within the `sayhello` function, `this` will reference `MyObject.foo` not `MyObject`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `MyObject.foo()` first so that the `this.sayhello` function actually gets added. Then you should beable to call `MyObject.foo.sayhello();`

Comment: This is wrong, you should be able to call `MyObject.sayhello()` not `MyObject.foo.sayhello()` because `this` references `MyObject`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyObject = {}
MyObject.foo = {
  sayhello: function(){
    alert('Hello');
  }
}
MyObject.foo.sayhello();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the function does not yet exist. Therefore you must call foo first. What you do is calling the function sayhello from the property foo. But you don't have a property foo. You have a function foo.

But you can also do this and make it chain, like jQuery does:

```
var MyObject = {}
MyObject.foo = function(){
  this.sayhello = function(){
    alert('Hello');
  }
  return this;
}
MyObject.foo().sayhello();
```

Make a function sayhello inside object foo, so not a chained function. But an object inside an object with a function.

```
var MyObject = {
    foo : {
        sayhello : function(){
            alert("hello");
        }
    }
}
MyObject.foo.sayhello(); // Now does work!
```

Comment: Yes but this means I have to use commas between methods, so netbeans navigator is not mapping the methods...