# What does it (function($) {})(); mean?

Tags: javascript

What does `(function($) {})();` mean?

Comment: Its an in-line function

Comment: The use of the `$` parameter looks bogus - like perhaps it was really supposed to be `jQuery(function ($) {..})` or `(function ($) {..})(jQuery)`. Make sure to write questions accurately.

Comment: `(function($) {})();` is a self executing anonymous function, same as here `(function(){} )();`
The difference is in first one you passed $ (jquery) as an argument to function. 
This function will be called as soon as it's parsed.

This has been already discussed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491650/self-executing-function-jquery-vs-javascript-difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).

It means that the code between the curly braces will be executed as soon as its parsed and inside a closure. This means that any variables declared inside the function body with `var` will be discarded from memory after the function is finished executing.  This is a way to isolate code and prevent namespace polution.  You can also use this to rename variables for a particular scope:

For example, consider jquery:

```
(function($){
  //inside the closure, jquery can be accessed using '$'
  $(...)
})(jquery);
```

or

```
(function(customJqueryName){
  //inside the closure, jquery can be accessed using 'customJqueryName'
  customJqueryName(...)
})(jquery);
```

Check out closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures
IIFE: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 0):

It's an anonymous inline-function, which will be called just after definition.

Comment: Essentially true, although one might like a use case, or at least the name for this pattern (IIFE), so one can put this answer in context.