# Bootstrap color picker not loading/working

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

I cannot understand why bootstrap color picker is not working. My code is the same as from the example I have used:
https:// itsjavi.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/

In the bundle config of my MVC app I have added

```
"~/Scripts/bootstrap-colorpicker.js",
"~/Scripts/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js",
"~/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css",
"~/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css",
```

The code in the main.aspx

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group demo2">
        <input type="text" value="#00AABB" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the code in the JS file

```
$(function () {
        $('.demo2').colorpicker();
 });
```

See what hapens

[My app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLvbM.jpg)

[How it should be screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfjkW.jpg)

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you check your dev tools console for errors?

Comment: As a general matter, you don't need to include both the `.min.js/css` and `.js/css` files - they have the same content. Also, are you certain your `Scripts` directory is actually uppercase?

Comment: in my opinion, but I can be wrong, you didn't write correctly your self executing function.
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491650/self-executing-function-jquery-vs-javascript-difference

Comment: @Fahrenheit With the `$` there, I believe this is the jQuery "page ready" function.

Comment: Can you try using an ID for the div and call that in your JS? So, try changing `<div class="input-group demo2">` to `<div id="demoID" class="input-group demo2">` perhaps and then call `$('.demoID').colorpicker();` ?

Comment: I've altered 
$(function () {
        $('.demo2').colorpicker();
        console.log(20);
    });

And the "20" is showing in the console. that means there is a problem with the  .colorpicker()   part?
No js errors in the console

Comment: @barry-johnson I think you are right, didn't remember writing it like this.

Georgy Georgiev, I created a fiddle with your case, can't reproduce your problem. Have you more informations to provide us with ?

https://jsfiddle.net/rpz9qks1/

Comment: @GurtejSingh It is improbable that in 2017 he has discovered a bug in jQuery's CSS selector functionality. Further, references by ID are prefixed by a `#` not a `.`, so at a minimum he would need to reference it by `$('#demoID')` if following your general suggestion.

Comment: @barry-johnson Sorry my bad! I meant # and not '.' I was just looking at the source of all the examples on that page, and they seem to use #. Never used this tool before. Was just trying to help!

Comment: Fahrenheit  can you tell me what references have you included?
I tired with IDs - still the same

Comment: The problem was missing png files but i had to replace all js and css files and references to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using bootstrap-colorpicker@2.5.3
I upgraded to bootstrap-colorpicker@3.2.0 and it fixed the issue
Hope it helped...

Answer (score 0):

The call to initialise the colorpicker should be against the **input** that it is intended to be use on... i.e. I believe your Main.aspx example is incorrect.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" value="#00AABB" class="form-control demo2" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the class for .demo2 has been moved to the input for which the picker is intended to manipulate the value of the input box as you use it's controls for picking a color.