# Doubts about an example of a javascript expression (vs statement)

Tags: javascript

I understand a **javascript expression** can be defined as "***producing a value***".

It seems the following is an expression:

```
function fun(){}//1
```

Because when enforcing the expression context with parentheses does not cause an error:

```
(function fun(){})//2
```

But then what is the value produced by the above expression (`//1`)?

Comment: log/alert it and you'll see

Comment: Find an explanation in this question. The value would be the function itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: @Banana Ummm... This is somewhat confusing because the above is called a "function declaration". Why then this function is an "expression"?

Comment: have a look [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326072/javascript-function-pointer-assignment)